# CSV parsing of uploaded file

Tags: python, google-app-engine, csv

I'm trying to parse the content of an uploaded csv file, but I get only "garbage" as output.

Here is how I read it:

```
reader = csv.reader(self.request.get('file').splitlines())
self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
for row in reader:
    self.response.out.write(str(row) + "\n")
```

The file is the following:

```
name,number,age
barf,123,34
blue,32,23
pluto,53,44
```

And here is my output:

```
['Content-Type: text/csv']
['Content-Length: 50']
['Content-MD5: YzBmNWJiZmNmYjQ3ZGY3NDFhNDFmODVmODhlZWFmMTk=']
['content-disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="maifile.csv"']
['X-AppEngine-Upload-Creation: 2014-01-28 14:33:33.735642']
[]
```

How can I get the content of the csv? I mean the header, the names and the numbers?

Thank you very much!

Comment: What web framework are you using? You are returning the *headers* of a multi-part form encoding, not the file contents itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a proper *multipart/form-data* POST, then the file upload field has a `.file` attribute that is going to be an actual *file-like object*; just pass *that* to the `csv.reader()`. Better to use `self.request.POST` here to make sure your upload is a `POST`ed parameter:

```
reader = csv.reader(self.request.get('file').file)

self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
for row in reader:
    self.response.out.write(str(row) + "\n")
```

If you are uploading the file as a blob to the blob storage, then you need to retrieve the actual blob file with a [`BlobReader`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/blobreaderclass):

```
from google.appengine.ext import blobstore
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import blobstore_handlers

class UploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
    def post(self):
        upload_files = self.get_uploads('file')

       reader = csv.reader(blobstore.BlobReader(upload_files[0]))

       self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
       for row in reader:
           self.response.out.write(str(row) + "\n")
```

where the call to `self.get_uploads()` actually causes the uploaded file to be transferred to the blob store.

Comment: I don't know if I'm using a multipart/form-data POST? I'm using a class UploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):def post(self): . Just removing the ".splitlines()" I get the same result, but all in a column, instead of rows (one charachter per line)

Comment: @UnableToLoad: How are you sending this data *to* your handler?

Comment: <form action="{{ url }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 Upload File: 
 <input type="file" name="file"><br> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

Comment: Wait a sec, why are you using a `BlobstoreUploadHandler` here?

Comment: It's needed for other stuff, I can remove the other stuff, to get that csv working, is it the problem?

Comment: @UnableToLoad: well, the handler uploads your file to the cloud storage instead; you'll need to retrieve the file from there; see https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/blobstorehandlers.

Comment: I don't understand, I don't need to upload the file now (later another file, but not this one). I removed the uploadhandler and used a classic webapp2.RequestHandler, but no difference. Sorry, I meant that I don't need to send a file back, I'm reading your link now

Comment: No, I was wrong; looking over the SDK source code it is clear nothing is uploaded to the blob storage until you call `self.get_uploads()`. You need the `.file` attribute of the field here.

Comment: using: self.response.out.write(str(self.get_uploads()[0])), I get <google.appengine.ext.blobstore.blobstore.BlobInfo object at 0x104cc3990> as answer, I think that I'm getting closer to the solution. What is the .file attribute?

Comment: @UnableToLoad: I meant: *don't* call `get_uploads()`; that file has now been uploaded to the [Blob store](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/) instead.

Comment: @UnableToLoad: But you can still access the file with `blobstore.BlobReader(self.get_uploads()[0])`, which gives you a file-like object that `csv.readen()` will take. See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/blobreaderclass

Comment: Yes it works! Thank you very much for the infinite patience and endurance!